# Find all elements in list that have a particular number in their name

Tags: python

```
import re 
chrs = ["chrom6", "chr2", "chr6", "chr4", "chr1", "chr16", " chrom8"]

def search_chrom(n, chrs):
    matches = []
    for c in chrs:
        m = re.search(f'^(?:chrom|chr){n}$', c)             
        if m:
            matches.append(m.group(0))
    print(matches)
    return matches
```

works with the first two asserts below but gives the output [] for the third. Why?

```
assert search_chrom(6, chrs) == ["chrom6", "chr6"]
assert search_chrom(16, chrs) == ["chr16"]
assert search_chrom(8, chrs) == ["chrom8"]
```

Comment: The best resource for regex is regex101.com. In https://regex101.com/r/3hmmA0/1/ you can find the pattern you posted and the input you provided. You can see how it only detects the ones starting with `"chrom"`. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: If that doesn't give you a hint you can look here https://regex101.com/r/3hmmA0/2/ for the solution.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried different ways to make it detect both chrom and chr but no luck. How can I tell it I mean starts with (^) either chrom or (|) chrom and ends with ($) whatever n is?

Comment: Oh, will have a look! @Adirio

Comment: I solved the `"chrom"` or `"chr"` issue, but the `"\d+"` I used will detect every number, try to adapt it to only accept the right number.

Comment: I give you the answer for `n == 6` in this link but you can work it out on your own: https://regex101.com/r/3hmmA0/3/

Comment: I am looking at this site: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp and they dont mention using an ? from what I can see. And how is that written inside the bracket? re.search(^(?:chrom|chr)\d+$)? As in n=6 can't I just write n$ ?

Comment: The `(?:    )` is all part of the same syntax. It means that all of that is a group. `(    )` does the same. The difference if you addd the `?:` at the start is that it makes it non-capturing. This means that you wont get a variable with "chrom" or "chr" in your output match. If you use normal brackets instead the substring that matches the part of the pattern inside the group will be saved as a variable in the match result you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex for this.

Python allows you to use the **in** keyword both for lists and strings.

In this case, a simple lookup will do:

```
chrs = ["chrom6", "chr6", "chrxxx"]
items = [x for x in chrs if '6' in x]
print(items)
```

But since you're asking if the pattern is correctly written, I would use this:

```
r = re.compile(f"^(chrom|chr){n}$")
```

Using Python 3's string interpolation to give the variable n to the pattern, and parenthesis around chrom|chr to make sure both are matched at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a regex `pattern = '^(?:chrom|chr)' + str(n) + '$'` would do a trick.
I used a group without capture to make a variant for a beginning. Your solution would only find `chrom` and `chr*6` (asterisk - any symbol).

Comment: `f'^(?:chrom|chr){n}$'` would also do the trick. The new `f'..'` format for formatting string is really readable.

Comment: Do you mean like this? m = re.search('^(?:chrom|chr)' + str(n) + '$', c)

Comment: @Adirio I did not use this when I was using Python. Always forget about it.

Comment: @Jose Felipe, yes. But you should use Adrillo's version as it is more readable

Comment: Ok! I changed it to m = re.search(f'^(?:chrom|chr){n}$', c) Can you help me with the continuation? I have been told it should be m.group(1).. @Adirio

Comment: @AntonioOne : )

Comment: @JoseFelipe `m.group(0)` should give you the whole `"chrom6"` or `"chr6"` string. `m.group(1)` would give you the first capturing block, which this regex has none of, as the `?:` makes is non-capturing. From `"chrom6"` what do you expect to get as `m.group(1)`? `"chrom"`?, `"6"`?

Comment: @Adirio you are right, I changed it to m.group(0) I'll add my updated code above, something still seems to be missing...

Comment: Your updated code seems right except for the commented list comprehension which needs to update the `0` and the pattern.

Comment: News! (please see the just updated question) It now works for the two first asserts shown but not the third? @Adirio

Comment: @JoseFelipe you have a space in `" chrom8"` which makes `chrom` not to be at the start of the line

Comment: Ohh, wow that you spotted that! Can I modify the re.search to allow for that to happen? @AntonioOne

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Use `f'^\s*(?:chrom|chr){n}\s*$'`. `\s` means any space symbol (space, tab, etc.). `*` makes it take any amount of such symbols, even 0

Comment: I would just drop `^`  (`f'(chrom|chr){n}$'`). If you go for the `\s*` option, the spaces will be included in your result list, as they will be part of `m.group(0)` but if you drop this sign they will not be included. The downside is that without them, strings like `"not-a-chrom6"` would result in a match were `m.group(0) == 'chrom6'`.

Comment: @JoseFelipe You could solve this in two ways:  
1) Make a capture group: `'f'((?:chrom|chr){n})$'` and use `m.group(1)` to see the result  
2) Use lookahead and lookbehind: `f'(^?<=\\s*)(?:chrom|chr){n}(?=\\s*$)'`  
PS. Also, I forgot to make double backslash in my previous suggestion. You could avoid this by using raw strings (`fr'your_string'`)